# First row of DataGrid is not finding on ItemDataBound in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DataGrid` where i am not able to find first row of the `DataGrid` on `ItemDataBound`.

its working fine With other continues rows.

`CS` code of  `ItemDataBound` is -

```
 protected void DgrMemberList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridItem item in DgrMemberList.Items)
        {
            HtmlAnchor aDelivery = e.Item.FindControl("aDelivery") as HtmlAnchor;
            if (e.Item.Cells[2].Text.ToString() == "STK")
            {
                aDelivery.HRef = "CreateDownloadImageSubmit.aspx?OID=" + e.Item.Cells[0].Text;
            }
            else
            {
                aDelivery.HRef = "javascript:void(0);";
            }
        }
}
```

Please help me out with this issue. 
Thanks

Comment: Why do you loop all items in `ItemDataBound` which is triggered for every item anyway? Btw, `DgrMemberList.Items` does not return the header or footer, only the `Item` or `AlternatingItem` as opposed to `ItemDataBound` which is trigered for every item-type.

Comment: in e.Item.Cells[2] there is many types of delivery like 'STK,KO,KWF,JSK' etc and i am bind the  `aDelivery.HRef` only for the 'STK' text

Comment: you have made foreach loop but where are you using "item"?

Comment: Actually i want to check the text of column values where if the value is 'STK' then the link of `<a>` is bind with id otherwise its bind `'javascript:void(0);'`

Comment: aDelivery.HRef = String.Format("CreateDownloadImageSubmit.aspx?OID= {0}", e.Item.Cells[0].Text); @GarimaRawat

Comment: if you debug then ur getting value when u put cursor on "e.Item.Cells[0].Text"??

Comment: i am getting values after 2nd row in `e.Item.Cells[0].Text` @Neel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62576/discussion-between-garima-rawat-and-neel).

Comment: silly to ask but are you sure you are really having values in first row?

Comment: sorry dear cant use chat during office time

Comment: @Neel ohh m sorry!! ,  for first row it was not going inside the foreach after that it is working fine

Comment: well I am confused here!!! "item" in foreach where are you using it in your code?

Comment: take a look on the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/urdo81ljqmse6lu/Capture.PNG?dl=0  in the picture u'll see three columns in 2nd row the number is link buttons. now i want to bind the link where the row value is 'STk'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't need to use loop in `DgrMemberList_ItemDataBound`. This event will be execute for every row in your grid.

```
 protected void DgrMemberList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.Row.DataItem == null)
          return;

      HtmlAnchor aDelivery = e.Item.FindControl("aDelivery") as HtmlAnchor;
      if (e.Item.Cells[2].Text.ToString() == "STK")
      {
           aDelivery.HRef = "CreateDownloadImageSubmit.aspx?OID=" + e.Item.Cells[0].Text;
      }
      else
      {
           aDelivery.HRef = "javascript:void(0);";
      }

 }
```

Comment: hehe now working fine if u don't mind can you please explain if i was using `DgrMemberList_ItemDataBound` what is exactly happening with code ?

Comment: yes right there was no need of foreach loop required @GarimaRawat

Comment: @Neel Sometimes mind goes in another  way that happen wid me for dis issue :D , Btw thanks for help